# Plot bar graph using the first column as x axe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame like this

```
action   | Mark | Linda | Paul | Sarah
goals    | 10   | 11    | 5    | 8  
assist   | 6    | 5     | 2    | 4
corners  | 1    | 6     | 5    | 2
```

I would like to create a bar plot to compare columns Mark Linda Paul Sarah by the action column.

I'm doins something like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = df[['Mark','Linda', 'Paul', 'Sarah']].plot(kind='bar', title ="Championship")
ax.set_xlabel("Action",fontsize=12)
```

I found this [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html), but it uses different arrays. Is there a way to iterate all the columns using the first to compare and create a bar chart?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
In [51]: import matplotlib

In [52]: matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

In [53]: df.set_index('action').plot.bar(title ="Championship", rot=0)
Out[53]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x93cb080>
```

[image]

Comment: @Hari, you are welcome! Thanks for accepting the answer! :)

Comment: You kindly help me! Bye!